# Rails railties gem error "undefined method: 'less'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I've just recently updated my rails app's gems with `gem update` and `bundle update`. When I tried to test it out with `rails s` it gives me this error:

`/Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in`method_missing': undefined method `less' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000010308a300> (NoMethodError)`

The rest of the error message goes like this:

```
from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.6/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine.rb:15:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Richard/Code/Rails/rgsimms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Richard/Code/Rails/rgsimms/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /Users/Richard/Code/Rails/rgsimms/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Richard/Code/Rails/rgsimms/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/Richard/Code/Rails/rgsimms/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/Richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Is this an error with the Twitter Bootstrap gem? I'm still learning so how would I get this fixed? Any help is awesome.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The twitter bootstrap gem depends on the less gem. From [the docs](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails):

```
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

I've personally found it easier for twitter bootstrap to just dump the files from the [official site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) into the vendor/assets directory. Updating from the gem is marginally easier than by hand, but when updating bootstrap, you kind of want to do it "by hand" and check it all out "by eye" anyway - I prefer the extra effort, to ensure it does not get done lightly. Also, it is very hard to remove certain (for example) responsive portions from the gem, without (as far as I could tell) "unspecifying" the styles. The responsive stuff changes, from version to version, in terms of size, so you can't just rely on it all working. I really can't see any advantage to using the gem.

**Update**

There is now an official gem for this, which I recommend checking out: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: Thanks, sir. I've removed the bootstrap gem and it's all working again. I used it after seeing it on Railscast.

Comment: For some reason, updating twitter made this error appear--  previous less and therubyracer had been in my gemfile, and I didn't know why.  Note that therubyracer is not reccomended on heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#troubleshooting

Comment: Bad idea.  Figure out why the gem isn't working right.  Now you will have to manually update this chunk of code every time you want a fix or version increment from bootstrap.  If you want to lock in a specific version, then do that in your Gemfile.

Comment: @Bill - you seem to have missed the point. You basically have to manually update every time, anyway. The gem adds no value. This describes both how to fix it, as you seem to require, as well as a good reason not to get it working. Try to work on your reading comprehension skills before forming strong opinions.

Comment: I took issue with putting the source in your assets folder.  The better solution would be to just fix up your depedencies.  It should also be noted that since twitter-bootstrap-rails is in the main group for most people, having less-rails in the assets group section will not fix this issue, it has to be in the main section as well, which is the primary issue most people seeing this error on upgrade will see.  Prior to version 2.1.6 of bootstrap rails which has less-rails included you either didn't need less-rails or could put it in the assets group.

Comment: According to the official documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), /vendor/assets is the appropriate place to put 3rd party assets... FWIW, the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem puts them in the exact same place - https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets . I just do not prefer to use the gem, for the reasons detailed above.

Comment: Another good reason to avoid it - http://blog.nvisium.com/2014/03/reflected-xss-vulnerability-in-twitter.html