# rails server can't be up, did bundle install but failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

> how do you solve this? i did bundle install yet i still get errors from below.

unable to run rails server when it shows all bundles are installed. please help me out.

```
Master:disrupreneurs shaunstanislaus$ bundle install
Using rake (10.0.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.7) 
Using activesupport (3.2.8) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.8) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.8) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.8) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.8) 
Using activeresource (3.2.8) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.8) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.5) 
Using faraday (0.8.4) 
Using hashie (1.2.0) 
Using httpauth (0.2.0) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.4) 
Using jwt (0.1.5) 
Using oauth (0.4.7) 
Using oauth2 (0.8.0) 
Using omniauth (1.1.1) 
Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1) 
Using omniauth-facebook (1.4.1) from git://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook.git (at                master)
Using omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.1.13) 
Using omniauth-google-plus-oauth2 (0.0.1) from https://github.com/luke-gru/omniauth-        google-plus-oauth2.git (at master) 
Using omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) 
Using omniauth-twitter (0.0.14) from https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter.git (at master) 
Using bundler (1.2.2) 
Using rails (3.2.8) 
Using rb-readline (0.4.2) 
Using rspec-core (2.12.0) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.12.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.12.0) 
Using rspec (2.12.0) 
Using sass (3.2.3) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.1.6) from git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-    rails.git (at master) 
Using uglifier (1.3.0) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

> from this part it keeps failing to run rails s
>
> how do i solve this'?

```
Master:disrupreneurs shaunstanislaus$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-    3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `less' for #    <Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fe5032ffa18> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-    rails-4ac83ab51931/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine.rb:15:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/Documents/developer/web/disrupreneurs/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/Documents/developer/web/disrupreneurs/config.ru:4:in `require'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/Documents/developer/web/disrupreneurs/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/Documents/developer/web/disrupreneurs/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/Documents/developer/web/disrupreneurs/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also add `gem 'less-rails'`

Check out this post too:

[Rails railties gem error "undefined method: 'less'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284077/rails-railties-gem-error-undefined-method-less)

Answer (score 1):

Add in gemfile:

```
gem "therubyracer"
```

and run bundle install again