# undefined method `less' when db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, less

When I try to db:migrate my app, I Get this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `less' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fdca55c75e0>
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-965ebd304f74/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine.rb:17:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

What could be wrong? I already have `gem 'less', '2.4.0'` in Gemfile

Comment: Yes, I have less in the Gemfile.lock

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284077/rails-railties-gem-error-undefined-method-less/13284226#13284226

Comment: do you have `gem less-rails` and `gem therubyracer` in Gemfile? or else please add that. https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap/issues/2

Comment: Thank you! adding gem less-rails in Gemfile fixed the problem :)

Comment: Please go through the link in the answer that would help you better. The same issue has been discussed there :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add therubyracer gem and less-rails gem

```
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

Please check the link for issue at the gem: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/437