# New user trying to install a Ruby Gem (bootstrap)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am new to rails and I'm trying to create a new project and add the bootstrap 3 ruby Gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass) and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

I create the new application:

```
rails new demoapp
```

I add the following line to the Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
```

I bundle it

```
bundle install
```

I run it

```
rails server
```

However no bootstrap is present on my site and I can't use bootstrap css, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add boot strap to the assets file.

> Import Bootstrap into a Sass file (for example, application.css.scss)
>   to get all of Bootstrap's styles, mixins and variables!

From https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Basically, add `@import "bootstrap";` to your application.css.scss file...

Comment: Incidentally, you may want to check out my rant at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284077/rails-railties-gem-error-undefined-method-less/13284226#13284226

Comment: This was the problem I had actually done this however my application.css.scss lacked the .scss extension so once I added this it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the gem inside the GemFile like

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

And then run the following command

```
bundle install
```

No need to run

```
gem install bootstrap-sass
```