# rails-bootstrap-forms applies some styles but not others

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using the rails-bootstrap-forms gem along with twitter-bootstrap-rails.  When I use the bootstrap_form_for function, I get forms that are only partially styled:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([@investor.property, @investor], layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10", role: "form") do |f| %>
  <% if @investor.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h4><%= pluralize(@investor.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this investor from being saved:</h4>
      <ul>
      <% @investor.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, label: "Name", placeholder: 'Your name here' %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, label: "Email", placeholder: 'you@example.com' %>
  <%= f.number_field :equity_share, label: "Equity share", placeholder: '% of total equity' %>
  <%= f.number_field :priority, label: "Priority", placeholder: 'Payment priority' %>
  <%= f.form_group do %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Generates:

[image]

Which you can see applies the horizontal layout but does not format the labels properly.  The HTML generated looks good:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/things/1/investors" class="form-horizontal" id="new_investor" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="QGzNsTGG41FPfnQ6n9yrka7caZayIu4fLpqToX5ASng=" /></div>
  <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="investor_name">Name</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="investor_name" name="investor[name]" placeholder="Your name here" type="text" /></div></div>
  <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="investor_email">Email</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="investor_email" name="investor[email]" placeholder="you@example.com" type="email" /></div></div>
  <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="investor_equity_share">Equity share</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="investor_equity_share" name="investor[equity_share]" placeholder="% of total equity" type="number" /></div></div>
  <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="investor_priority">Priority</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control" id="investor_priority" name="investor[priority]" placeholder="Payment priority" type="number" /></div></div>
  <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2"></label><div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="btn btn-default" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div></div></form>
```

And I have not (to my knowledge) overridden any of the Bootstrap CSS or other formatting.  The "icon:" command also does not change the output at all, if that's a useful clue.  What might be the issue?  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:  I have attempted to replace twitter-bootstrap-rails with bootstrap-sass following Brad Werth's suggestion.  However, I get an "unclosed block" error in application.css.scss whenever I include the @import "bootstrap"; line. Here is the contents of application.css.scss:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require rails_bootstrap_forms
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
*/
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
```

"custom" is just my site's basic css.  I only get an error if the @import "bootstrap"; line is included, regardless of other lines or the require statements.

Comment: I guess your assets are not compiling.

Comment: That does sound right.  "rake assets:precompile" does not fix it...is there another approach?

Comment: Did you use some sort of a generator to create the rails template? Confirm that you have included the bootstrap css properly.

Comment: I ran "rails generate bootstrap:install less"

Comment: If I comment out the first two @import lines of the bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file, my nav_tabs and other Bootstrap features disappear.  Clearly, some Bootstrap CSS is getting through.

Comment: best to post what the file looks like that someone can look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue finally resolved itself when I upgraded to Ruby 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I would [dump twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284226/525478), if possible, and use the official version at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass .

Comment: Trying this, I get an "unclosed block" compile error on the @import "bootstrap"; command in application.css.scss.  It seems that this gem is having a hard time finding Bootstrap as well!

Comment: Hmm... weird. I've never seen that one before. I wonder if you have any remnants or conflicting elements kicking around in your assets or vendor/asset directories, or something... It may even be inone of hte files preceding bootstrap in your application.css.scss, although I imagine it's pretty close to the top...

Comment: I agree it definitely seems like a conflict.  I have literally nothing in the vendor assets, and (see update) the import statements are at the top of application.css.scss.  I'm really quite stumped.

Comment: Yeah, ditto. The only advice I could give would be to make a commit and then just start ripping stuff out of your app, until you hit on the magic element or delete everything in your entire app_root. Not terribly helpful, I know, but you've clearly got something exerting an unexpected influence. One place to start might be public/assets, in case anything snuck in there... Good luck, sorry I didn't have the silver bullet.

Comment: As one of the maintainers of the gem, I'd like more feedback than that. We have a good gem, people should use it if it fits their needs.

Comment: The feedback can be found in the first link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284077/rails-railties-gem-error-undefined-method-less/13284226#13284226). Basically (for me), it is unnecessary, doesn't solve any issues, is superseded by an official version, and introduces security risks. If the helpers could fully abstract away the implementation discrepancies between the various bootstrap versions it would be more useful to me. It seems to me that the helpers are the real potential value of this gem, now that an official solution exists. Thanks for your contributions, they're just not 4 me.

Answer (score 0):

You can import individual sheets in twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and skip forms.less if you prefer the CSS that comes with rails-bootstrap-forms. Also you can always test things using the Teststrap app: http://teststrap.herokuapp.com.

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-stylesheets-with-less

Edit: I went ahead and installed both gems in teststrap and was not able to duplicate this issue. I suspect there is something else happening, and if you want me to look at your project to figure it out send me a message.